# How do u add 2decimals points into this function code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateTotal() {
    document.getElementById("Total1").value = document.getElementById("Unit1").value * document.getElementById("quantity1").value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the values of inputs are numbers by parse  Float()
Then you can use the toFixed() method in JavaScript to format a number with two decimals. The toFixed() method formats a number with a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The elements don't have a .value property, instead you can use `.textContent` to get and change the value stored.

If you are working with numbers only, you can use [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round the product.

```
const quantityEl = document.getElementById("quantity1");
const unitEl = document.getElementById("unit1");

// .toFixed() takes a parameter for number of digits to appear after decimal, in this case 2
const val = (quantityEl.textContent * unitEl.textContent).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("value").textContent = val;
```